# How to check if Flutter Text widget was overflowed

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Text widget which can be truncated if it exceeds a certain size:

```dart
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50.0),
  child: Text(
    widget.review,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  )
);
```

Or max number of lines:

```dart
RichText(
  maxLines: 2,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  text: TextSpan(
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    text: widget.review,
  ));
```

My goal is to have the text expandable **only if** an overflow occurred. Is there a proper way of checking if the text overflowed?

### What I've tried

I have found that in RichText, there is a `RenderParagraph renderObject` , which has a private property `TextPainter _textPainter` which has a `bool didExceedMaxLines`.

In short, I just need to access `richText.renderObject._textPainter.didExceedMaxLines` but as you can see, it is made private with the underscore.

Answer (score 43):

I found a way to do it. Full code below, but in short:

1. Use a LayoutBuilder to determine how much space we have.
2. Use a TextPainter to simulate the render of the text within the space.

Here's the full demo app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Text Overflow Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("DEMO")),
        body: TextOverflowDemo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextOverflowDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditorState createState() => _EditorState();
}

class _EditorState extends State<TextOverflowDemo> {
  var controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        mytext = controller.text;
      });
    });
    controller.text = "This is a long overflowing text!!!";
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  String mytext = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int maxLines = 1;
    double fontSize = 30.0;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, size) {
            // Build the textspan
            var span = TextSpan(
              text: mytext,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
            );

            // Use a textpainter to determine if it will exceed max lines
            var tp = TextPainter(
              maxLines: maxLines,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              text: span,
            );

            // trigger it to layout
            tp.layout(maxWidth: size.maxWidth);

            // whether the text overflowed or not
            var exceeded = tp.didExceedMaxLines;

            return Column(children: <Widget>[
              Text.rich(
                span,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: maxLines,
              ),
              Text(exceeded ? "Overflowed!" : "Not overflowed yet.")
            ]);
          }),
          TextField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I tried the other solution which just states using TextPainter, but the issue is, we can't get the renderObjectSize when we are building the widget. Hence, didExceedMaxLines always returned true.

Comment: Important note; `didExceedMaxLines` calculation won't be accurate when the device scales font sizes up (or down); think: vision impairment for example. To accurately support this, add: 

`textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor` 

to the `TextPainter` initialisation.

Comment: Awesome, but how can I get Text Direction from localization?

Comment: I am using widget span. TextPainter cannot create widget span. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 30):

There is a shorter way to get an answer if text is overflowed or not. You just need to define textStyle and get the answer from this method

```
bool hasTextOverflow(
  String text, 
  TextStyle style, 
  {double minWidth = 0, 
       double maxWidth = double.infinity, 
       int maxLines = 2
  }) {
  final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
    text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
    maxLines: maxLines,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  )..layout(minWidth: minWidth, maxWidth: maxWidth);
  return textPainter.didExceedMaxLines;
}
```

Comment: A great function, thanks very much for sharing! I might add that it is (probably) more commonly used with maxLines = 1, which I'd set as a default for an example.

Comment: Good function, maxWidth will be device width. so you may get exact bool of didExceedMaxLines as true. otherwise if maxWidth == double.infinity always gives false.

Answer (score 16):

You can use a flutter plug-in `auto_size_text` at [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text#-readme-tab-).
When the text is get overflowed, you can set some widget to be appeared.

```
int maxLines = 3;
String caption = 'Your caption is here';
return AutoSizeText(
    caption,
    maxLines: maxLines,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    minFontSize: 15,
    overflowReplacement: Column( // This widget will be replaced. 
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        caption,
        maxLines: maxLines,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
      Text(
        "Show more",
        style: TextStyle(color: PrimaryColor.kGrey),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Best and most efficient solution thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Building on the other solutions provided, here's a generalized Widget that may be useful.

```
/// Checks the text provided and style, and then calls
/// the provided builder function with whether the text
/// will overflow the maxLines value
class DetectTextOverflowBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text textWidget;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, bool) builder;
  final int maxLines;

  const DetectTextOverflowBuilder({
    super.key,
    required this.textWidget,
    required this.builder,
    this.maxLines = 1,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final defaultTextStyle = DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style;

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final span = TextSpan(
          text: textWidget.data,
          style: textWidget.style ?? defaultTextStyle,
        );

        // Use a textpainter to determine if it will exceed max lines
        final tp = TextPainter(
          maxLines: maxLines,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          text: span,
        );

        // trigger it to layout
        tp.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);

        // whether the text overflowed or not
        final exceeded = tp.didExceedMaxLines;

        return builder(context, exceeded);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Follows the builder pattern, with the builder function being passed the context and a `bool willOverflow` indicating whether the text widget will overflow the layout builders maxWidth.

Advantage of this approach in my opinion are

- Reusability
- Increased flexibility in terms of being able to control what gets displayed based on whether or not the text will have overflowed the available space
- Doesn't display the text content by default

**Example usage:**

[Example widget view collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVUSy.png) |
[Example widget view expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOsMS.png)

```
class ShowMoreDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowMoreDemo({super.key});

  @override
  ShowMoreDemoState createState() => ShowMoreDemoState();
}

class ShowMoreDemoState extends State<ShowMoreDemo> {
  bool isShowingMore = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final messageContent = Text(
      AppConstant.loremText,
      maxLines: isShowingMore ? 40 : 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    );

    return DetectTextOverflowBuilder(
      textWidget: messageContent,
      builder: (context, willOverflow) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            messageContent,
            SizedBox(height: 20.h),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                const Text('4 days ago'),
                if (willOverflow)
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      isShowingMore = !isShowingMore;
                    }),
                    child: Text(
                      isShowingMore ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More',
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made my own Widget i use it cross the project, it take `Text` widget in the constructor and reads the properties of it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverflowDetectorText extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text child;

  OverflowDetectorText({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tp = TextPainter(
      maxLines: child.maxLines,
      textAlign: child.textAlign ?? TextAlign.start,
      textDirection: child.textDirection ?? TextDirection.ltr,
      text: child.textSpan ?? TextSpan(
        text: child.data,
        style: child.style,
      ),
    );

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constrains) {
        tp.layout(maxWidth: constrains.maxWidth);
        final overflowed = tp.didExceedMaxLines;
        if (overflowed) {
          //You can wrap your Text `child` with anything
        }
        return child;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solution need `maxLines` to be passed, but in my case I do not have specific number of maxLines as it is dependent on device screen height.

This solution will also update UI at runtime if user increase device font size from control centre in iOS or from settings in Android.

The way I solved is here:

1. Calculate total height needed by your text (with style) using Text-Painter.
2. Figure out available space you have got, and render UI based on difference.

```
class OverflowText extends StatelessWidget {
  const OverflowText({super.key, required this.text, this.style});

  final TextStyle? style;
  final String text;

  double _heightRequired(
    String text,
    TextStyle? style,
    double maxWidth,
    TextScaler textScaler,
  ) {
    final tp = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      textScaler: textScaler,
    )..layout(maxWidth: maxWidth);
    return tp.size.height;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final media = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final heightRequired = _heightRequired(
          text,
          style,
          constraints.maxWidth,
          media.textScaler,
        );
        final willTruncate = heightRequired > constraints.maxHeight;
        if (willTruncate) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  text,
                  style: style,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                  minimumSize: const Size(0, 0),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  'Read More',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
        return Text(text, style: style);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://imgur.com/a/7SCpT8n)