# Resizeable BasicTextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

Is there a way to produce a resizeable BasicTextField in Jetpack Compose, so that its width would wrap text size when a user types in or deletes characters? They've solved a similar problem for flutter, but I didn't find out how to solve this for Compose.
[Flutter - how to make TextField width fit its text ("wrap content")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505327/flutter-how-to-make-textfield-width-fit-its-text-wrap-content/64380602#64380602)

```kotlin
var text: String by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
BasicTextField(
   value = text,
   onValueChange = {
       text = it
   },
   modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth()
)
```

unfortunately, `wrapContentWidth()` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well, looks like `width(IntrinsicSize.Min)` solves this problem:

```
var text: String by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
BasicTextField(
   value = text,
   onValueChange = {
       text = it
   },
   modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
)
```

Comment: This really worked. You saved me !

Comment: wow, so the only solution worked for me, any clue why .wrapContentHeight() is not applicable?

Comment: I tried same concept to resize height but it did not work

Comment: Its works only without TextAlign for me

Answer (score 4):

We can specify the width range ( min and max width that the textField can span )

for width:-

```
modifier = Modifier.widthIn(1.dp, Dp.Infinity) // specified the min width as 1.dp
```

for height:-

```
modifier = Modifier.heightIn(1.dp, Dp.Infinity)
```

The composable code:-

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
     OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
           text = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier.widthIn(1.dp, Dp.Infinity)
     )
}
```

The `TextField` would grow when we type more till `Dp.Infinity`. ( used `OutlinedTextField` for demo but we can use `BasicTextField` )

[image]

Comment: Oh great that was helpful!

Comment: But there's still a problem. Looks like this `min = 1.dp` you used would never be reached. Outline is much larger then text if it contains less then 10 characters, `TextField` probably has fixed minimal width... which I need to get rid of

Comment: It works when you type some value but you have in any case a minWidth >1.dp when you delete the characters.

Comment: yes its always keeping a minimum size by default, after which its resizable.

Comment: Ok, then how do I change this default minSize to 10.dp or so? @SantanuSur