# How to auto size text field in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

In xml based layouts we can set `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` in the edit text to auto size the text font. But similar feature is not available in compose `TextField`. Please suggest if there is any alternative way of doing it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971569/androidautosizetexttype-in-jetpack-compose/66490475#66490475) help?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bmc08gt/e890e63124846e02f6afb38ee27e9f9c

Comment: Try the below solution. It's works for me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64380602/9794122)

Comment: Thanks gangs for you help

Answer (score 1):

You can try following solution

```
@Composable
fun Int.scaledSp(): TextUnit {
    val value: Int = this
    return with(LocalDensity.current) {
        val fontScale = this.fontScale
        val textSize =  value / fontScale
        textSize.sp
  }
```

Comment: Would you please add a use case?