# How can I conditionally render a different widget if the original overflows on device in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

If a `Text("This is a very big string of text")` does not fit on the screen, how can I instead show a different and smaller `Text()` widget?

EDIT: For clarification. What I want is, if a widget overflows, to show a different widget, doesn't have to be limited to text.

Thanks.

Comment: Wrap your `Text` widget in the `Container`. If there is horizontal overflow, it will break and remaining text will be shown below.

Comment: @AyushBherwani thank you but that is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to wrap text

Comment: Do you want a responsive text?

Comment: I've edited my question. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: You can check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272545/8220468

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
(showDifferentText ? Text("Different text") : Text("This is a very big string of text"))
```

Here `showDifferentText` is bool.