# How to detect text overflow in flutter_html

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-html

I have managed to limit html content by using maxlines property of Style and display "show more" text in case the content overflows the maxlines value.

```
Html( data: notifications[index] .longDescription, shrinkWrap: true, style: { 'body': Style( maxLines: notifications[ index] .isExpaned ? 10000 : 2, textOverflow: TextOverflow .ellipsis) }),
```

Now the problem is to detect if the widget has overflowed or not because i have to hide "view more" option in case the content is less than 2 lines.

Can anyone suggest any alternate way of getting List of TextSpan in flutter_html^2.1.0 so that I can use that list like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65408733/8884969)

[image]

Comment: You can check this similar answer here: [hasTextOverflow method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65408733/14269222)

Comment: @SuatÖzkaya thanks for your reply! This answer is using plain text whereas in my scenario I am working on text from Html widget which is not plain text.

Comment: Also, there is a package called [readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore). A Flutter plugin than allow expand and collapse text.
Maybe someone reading here can find it useful.