# Show Tooltip just when text is trimmed because of overflow

Tags: flutter, tooltip, word-wrap

I am displaying Tooltip on top of a Text, letting user see the full name of person, but it shows Tooltip, either when text has overflown or not:

```
child: Tooltip(
                message: fullNameWithTitle,
                child: Text(
                  fullNameWithTitle,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
```

But how can I set Tooltip in such a way that displays just if text is trimmed by ellipsis?

Comment: I think this will help using flutter plug-in auto_size_text https://stackoverflow.com/a/60637243/11445727

Comment: Hi, I didn't get your question well, Specially "either when text has overflown or not:" part, Can you elaborate please? I think I can help you with this case.

Comment: I have the same question, so to elaborate:
The goal is to be able to display a tooltip only when the text overflows. If the complete text is displayed, no need to display a tooltip.
In many cases as mine, for example text displayed in cells of a table, you don't want to reduce font size like a plug like plug-in auto_size_text will do, because it will create a visual imbalance with others texts elements.
I've seen lot of solutions for classical html/css/js environnement, but I can't find any solution for now for flutter...

Comment: Few month later, I'm still searching for a solution to this issue.
Maybe few evolutions in flutter that allows to do this now?

Answer (score 2):

If someone is interested in this question, I've finally created a component that works, using a TextPainter inside a LayoutBuilder to be able to check the overflow and then apply a tooltip only when necessary. (Credit to @Lian explanations [in this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114778/how-to-check-if-flutter-text-widget-was-overflowed)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextAutoTooltip extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextAutoTooltip({
    Key? key,
    this.text = '',
    this.tooltipText,
    this.showTooltip = true,
    this.maxLines = 1,
    this.style,
    this.textAlign = TextAlign.left,
    this.overflow = TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    this.preferBelow = false,
    this.verticalOffset,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// Text to be displayed
  final String? text;

  /// Specifiy the text to be displayed for the tooltip (when text is overflowing)
  /// If not specified, the tooltip text will be the original text displayed.
  final String? tooltipText;

  /// Specify whether to display the tooltip when overflowing, or not.
  final bool showTooltip;

  /// maxLine for the text to be displayed in
  final int? maxLines;

  /// Style of the text
  final TextStyle? style;

  /// Text alignment
  final TextAlign? textAlign;

  /// Text type of overflow
  final TextOverflow? overflow;

  /// Whether the tooltip defaults to being displayed below the widget.
  final bool? preferBelow;

  /// Tooltip verticalOffset
  final double? verticalOffset;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, size) {
        // Creation of a TextSpan
        TextSpan span = TextSpan(
          text: text,
          style: style,
        );

        // Creation of a TextPainter which will be used to determine whether there is an overflow or not (in fact when max lines will be exceeded)
        TextPainter tp = TextPainter(
          maxLines: maxLines,
          textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor, // to be accurate when the device scales font sizes up (or down)
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          text: span,
        );

        // The TextPainter is linked to the layout
        tp.layout(maxWidth: size.maxWidth);

        // Then we get back the overflow info from the TextPainter "didExceedMaxLines" property
        bool isOnOverflow = tp.didExceedMaxLines;

        return Tooltip(
          message: isOnOverflow && showTooltip ? tooltipText ?? text : '',
          verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
          preferBelow: preferBelow,
          child: Text.rich(
            span,
            overflow: overflow,
            maxLines: maxLines,
            textAlign: textAlign,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then it can be used as a systematic replacement of the classic "Text" component.

Comment: @Meini: glad it helped! In my case, it added a big plus to the application that I'm developing.